# How to get the progress bar to show using Fineuploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the progress bar to show when uploading a file using the fineuploader code.

Here's my code:

```
$("#attachmentUpload").fineUploader({
    element: $('#attachmentUpload')[0],
    request: {
        endpoint: '/controls/UploadFile.aspx'

    },
    autoUpload: true,
    multiple: false,
    text: {
        uploadButton: '<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Select File">',
        formatProgress: '({percent}% of {total_size})'
    },
    debug: true

}).on('submit', function (event, id, filename) {
    //when file is submitted code here
    alert('submitted');
}).on('complete', function (event, id, filename, responseJSON) {
    //when upload is finished code here
    alert('done');
});
```

When I perform a file upload I can see the loading gif animation, the file name, file size, and the word "Processing...".  The file upload completes successfully, but I just haven't been able to figure out how to get the progress bar to display.  I've tried in Chrome, IE 10, and Firefox.  None of them display the progress bar or the content of the formatProgress text option.

More info:  I'm using the FineUploader mode.

Comment: Correction:  Firefox is actually showing the file upload progress.  It must not be supported in Chrome and IE10?

Comment: More info:  According to this website (http://caniuse.com/fileapi)  Chrome 25 and IE 10 both support the file API and I verified that I have those versions, but they do not show the progress bar.  Only Firefox shows the progress bar on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can assure you that the progress bars work just fine in Fine Uploader for all supported browsers that support the File API.  This, of course, includes Chrome.  If you are uploading a small file on a very fast connection, the progress bar will likely not be visibile due to the almost-instant upload.

The "Processing..." status message appears after the last byte has been sent and we are waiting for a response from the server.  I have explained why "Processing..." does not reliably appear in Firefox (and the progress bar lingers until the server returns a response) in [a case in Fine Uploader's issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/404#issuecomment-10124160).  Please read [my comments](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/404#issuecomment-10124160) for more info.

Comment: Ray, it's been a long time since I last checked my stackoverflow account.  I did not realize I had received a response to this question and you are right, I discovered that the issue was due to a CSS error on the page and not a problem with the fineuploader tool.  Thank you for your response.